# Close mission control by repeating gesture

Tags: trackpad, mission-control, multi-touch

Currently I have mission control to activate on three fingers up as so

[image]

However once mission control is activated I would expect to be able to close mission control by repeating this three fingers up gesture. Or at least that's how I had it configured on a previous mac. How can I restore this functionality?

Comment: People are also complaining about this here https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/4s5mjm/macos_sierra_slow_animations_mission_control/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple officially responded this is no longer supported.